How to find the direct put address for firehose?
I created a aws firehose stream with source input: direct put.
Where do i see the address now, i can send the data to. I can not find it.

You don't need an address or Endpoints. You need to make sure you have proper permission to put records in the firehose. You just need the name of the firehose along with the region where it resides and you are good to go.
Here is an example code:
import datetime
import json
import random
import boto3

STREAM_NAME = "<STREAM_NAME>"
REGION_NAME = "<REGION>"

def get_data():
    """Generate random data."""
    return {
        'EVENT_TIME': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
        'CITY': random.choice(['NYC', 'ITL', 'ABD', 'SRT', 'THI','HYD']),
        'TICKER': random.choice(['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT', 'INTC', 'TBV']),
        'PRICE': round(random.random() * 100, 2)
    }

def generate(stream_name, firehose_client):
    """Generate and send data to Kinesis Data Firehose."""
    while True:
        data = get_data()
        try:
            firehose_client.put_record(
                DeliveryStreamName=stream_name,
                Record={
                    'Data': json.dumps(data)
                }
            )
            print("Data sent successfully:", data)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    firehose_client = boto3.client('firehose', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    generate(STREAM_NAME, firehose_client)


So the put method is just for boto3?

Yes, you will require to use AWS SDK in order to put data in stream.
